# Using Let's Encrypt with subdomains handled by Nginx's wildcard

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, lets-encrypt

I'm setting up a debian server with nginx and I want to be able to serve my web services with HTTPS. I'm still learning and I found myself lost in nginx+let's encrypt configuration.

First question:

Do I have to provide certbot with all the subdomains that I am going to create thanks to nginx (sub.domain.com)

```
certbot certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d domain.com -d sub1.domain.com -d sub2.domain.com
```

or can I just give my main domain (domain.com) and it will generate one set of certificates that I can use afterwards thanks to nginx

```
certbot certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d domain.com
```

Second question:

I set up my server following Nginx + Let's Encrypt + Debian DigitalOcean tutorial.

I went to my domain DNS and I've given a wildcard to my nginx server so that it handles the subdomains.

```
  A      domain.com     SERVER_IP
CNAM    *.domain.com    domain.com
```

And I want to be able to create a default file in my sites-enabled folder that handles every network connection made to port 80 and forward it to the right subdomain service. And I want to be able to create for each of my subdomains a file with its server block that will allow me to explicitely say if I want or I don't want SSL for that specific domain.

My default file looks like this right now:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

        # SSL configuration

        listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
        resolver_timeout 5s;
        # Disable preloading HSTS for now.  You can use the commented out header line that includes
        # the "preload" directive if you understand the implications.
        #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

        #root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user1/website/website.sock;
        }       


        location ~/.well-known {
                allow all;
        }
}
```

and I have a host in an other file that uses my main domain to deploy a flask app with ssl:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP_OF_MY_SERVER;

    ssl on;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user1/website/website.sock;
    }
}
```

now I want to create subdomain for my other web services, what I do is I create a new host file in sites-enabled, for example transmission web ui (I want it without SSL):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sub1.domain.com;

        ssl off;

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://localhost:9091/;
        }

        location /transmission {
                proxy_pass      http://localhost:9091/transmission;
        }
}
```

And another flask app (I want it with SSL):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub2.domain.com;

    ssl on;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user2/flaskapp2/flaskapp2.sock;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately everything that I tried led to HSTS errors or another kind of error. Maybe my use case is not possible. I would be very grateful if somebody can explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check your DNS settings with https://acme-check.com/ to find errors

Answer (score -1):

To your first question. It's not possible to use wildcard for letsencrypt certificates.

Comment: this is now possible : https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-and-wildcard-certificate-support-is-live/55579